# Hide top UISearchBar when scrolling up, stick it on top when scrolling down just like in Facebook iOS app

Tags: ios

In the Facebook iOS app, when user scrolls up the top UISearchBar is hidden but when the user scrolls down it stays on top.

How can I achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` of you `UIScrollView`, `UITableView`, etc., in order to handle the scroll down, and make the bar to stay at position y = 0:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if(offsetY < 0.0f) {
        searchBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, MAX(offsetY, 0));
    }
}
```

Note the search bar is inside the Scroll view.

Comment: Do I put the searchBar as a row in the UITableVIew or just a header view of section?

Comment: Just as header, so it will move together with the table content.

Comment: Remember to set the UIScrollView delegates properly.